# How do we send a report using FIX protocol using Quickfixj

Tags: fix-protocol

I have a CSV report where I have to send the report using FIX protocol to the counterparty.
I tried using quickfixj ,but was not able to send a logon.

Session.sendToTarget is returning false .as well I see in the events logs:created session no responder ..resetting session.Could you please advice what is going wrong?
Also want to know how is the data dictionary being read when we set it as true in the config file using quickfixj.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is rather a big question. You've got to configure QuickFix to connect to your counterparty. You've got to implement the QuickFix Application with which you'd transfer your CSV data to FIX message key value pairs.

The thing to do is look at the example application, [Banzai](http://www.quickfixj.org/quickfixj/usermanual/1.6.1/usage/examples.html)

You use the config file to set the location for the data dictionary you use

Comment: Pls see my detailed question over here:FIX:How to send ,messages using FIX ,quickfixj

Many Thanks,Kini

Comment: You mean [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42745874/fixhow-to-send-messages-using-fix-quickfixj)